# Oracle 11g: only return a value if row is first or last in group

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a report from an Oracle query. The data is like this:

```
GROUP_ID | COUNT_1 | COUNT_2
    1    |   100   |   123
    1    |   101   |   123
    1    |   283   |   342
    1    |   134   |   123
    2    |   241   |   432
    2    |   321   |   920
    2    |   432   |   121
    2    |   135   |   342
```

What I would like to do is only return the GROUP_ID when its the first in the group, and also some other value when its the last in the group, e.g.

```
GROUP_ID | COUNT_1 | COUNT_2
    1    |   100   |   123
         |   101   |   123
         |   283   |   342
   last  |   134   |   123
    2    |   241   |   432
         |   321   |   920
         |   432   |   121
   last  |   135   |   342
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of "first in the group" and "last in the group"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not tested, but this should be the idea. If you need to sort by COUNT_1 or COUNT_2, you should include it in the analytic functions' `over` clause, `partition by GROUP_ID order by COUNT_1`

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm) to understand what an analytic function is.

```
select
  case when ROW_NUMBER = 1 then GROUP_ID
       when ROW_NUMBER = GROUP_COUNT then 'last'
       else NULL
  end GROUP_ID
  ,COUNT_1
  ,COUNT_2
from(
    select
      GROUP_ID
      ,COUNT_1
      ,COUNT_2
      ,row_number() over(partition by GROUP_ID) ROWNUMBER
      ,count(GROUP_ID) over (partition by GROUP_ID) GROUP_COUNT
    from
      FOO
)
```

Comment: :Your SQL is corrected ,please find the [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0baa/20)

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE tt(g NUMBER, c1 NUMBER, c2 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(1, 100, 123);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(1, 101, 123);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(1, 283, 342);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(1, 134, 123);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(2, 241, 432);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(2, 321, 920);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(2, 432, 121);
INSERT INTO tt VALUES(2, 135, 342);

SELECT CASE WHEN 1=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g ORDER BY c1 ASC,  c2 ASC) THEN '1'
            WHEN 1=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g ORDER BY c1 DESC, c2 DESC) THEN 'Last'
            ELSE 'Empty'
        END answer,
       c1, c2
  FROM tt;

1        100  123
Empty    101  123
Empty    134  123
Last     283  342
1        135  342
Empty    241  432
Empty    321  920
Last     432  121
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `lag()` and `lead()` analytical functions:

```
with a as (
   select 1 group_id, 100 count_1, 123 count_2 from dual union all
   select 1 group_id, 101 count_1, 123 count_2 from dual union all
   select 1 group_id, 283 count_1, 342 count_2 from dual union all
   select 1 group_id, 134 count_1, 123 count_2 from dual union all
   select 2 group_id, 241 count_1, 432 count_2 from dual union all
   select 2 group_id, 321 count_1, 920 count_2 from dual union all
   select 2 group_id, 432 count_1, 121 count_2 from dual union all
   select 2 group_id, 135 count_1, 342 count_2 from dual 
)
select
  case lag (group_id) over (order by group_id, count_1) 
    when group_id then 
      case lead (group_id) over (order by group_id, count_1)
      when group_id then null
           else 'last'
      end
    else to_char(group_id) end x,
  count_1,
  count_2
from
a;
```

with `lag(group_id) over (order by group_id, count_1)` you get the `group_id` of the *previous* record (it lags behind). Similarly, with `lead(group_id) over...` you get the group_id of the *next* record.

With the `case` expression, you compare the *current* `group_id` with the *next* and *previous* one and then return the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it looks like there are several ways of achieving this. I've tried out a modified version of Erkan Haspulat's answer which seemed to work fine, as does your answer. Are there any performance benefits of one over the other?